# Ошибка в  запросе к БД, а именно неправильный синтаксис

Tags: php, mysql

Ошибка в

**WHERE surname='$surname_parent'");** потому, что если написать

**WHERE surname='Бухарова'");** то находит

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int FROM datacenter                         WHERE surname='$surname_parent'");

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo '<li>';
    echo $row['class_int'];
    echo '</li>';
}

if ($result) {
    echo 'Успешно';
} else {
    echo 'Ошибка';
}
```

Comment: Может в таблице пусто?

Comment: нет, я не правильно написал переменную.

Comment: добавтье echo "SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int FROM datacenter                         WHERE surname='$surname_parent'"; и проверьте что в вашем запросе не так)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте `var_dump( $surname_parent )` перед запросом

P.S: Я-бы переписал код, как минимум, так:

```
$result = mysql_query('
   SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int
   FROM datacenter
   WHERE surname="'.$surname_parent.'"
');

if ( $result == false ) echo 'Ошибка БД';
else {
  if ( mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ) echo 'Данные не найдены';
  else{
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
        echo '<li>'.$row['class_int'].'</li>';
    }

    echo 'Успешно';
  }
}
```

Comment: не работает пишет успешно, а мне надо что-бы выводило class_int

Comment: о все спс)